# First order D.E.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

What is the proper solution to $y'=-\sqrt{y}$? Obviously, $2\sqrt{y}=C-x$. But for $x>C$, $\sqrt{y}<0$ and so, $y'<0$. Is the solution then that $y=\frac{1}{4}(C-x)^2$ for $x\le C$ and $y=0$ $x>C$?

Comment: Yes your final solution is correct. It's a $C^1$ function satisfying the ODE. You may note btw that solutions to this ODE for an initial condition $y(x_0)=0$ are not unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution will be defined until $x=C$, and then die out. It will not be defined over $\mathbb{R}$. In fact, it can not be defined after $x=C$, as we deduce from the formula you wrote yourself:

$$ 2 \sqrt{y} = -x+C $$

as that would require $\sqrt{y}$ to assume negative values.

Comment: So if you extend the domain to $\mathbb{C}$, then what would the solution look like?

Comment: I don't think that would make sense. If it does I have never heard of anything similar.